# How can I implement a linked list in fortran 2003-2008

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, fortran, fortran90

I need to implement a link list data structure for my molecular dynamics code in fortran 2003/2008 I am using the newest fortran compilers (Intel).

How do I come about implement the linked list in the best way possible I would prefer a lock-free no wait implementation if possible in Fortran.

Thank you.

Comment: a simple google search should give you numerous examples. For example, http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n2a2.htm and http://cs.ubishops.ca/ljensen/fortran/pointer.htm

Comment: Any commnts on th lock-free issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easiest if you create a user defined type with your data items and the pointer to the next item.  This is assuming a singly-linked list.  e.g.,

```
   type MyList_type
      integer :: FirstItem
      real :: SecondItem
      etc
      type (MyList_type), pointer :: next_ptr => null ()
   end type MyList_type
```

Then create the first member with "allocate".    Thereafter you write code to traverse the list, using next_ptr to step through the list.  Use the "associated" intrinsic function to test whether next_ptr is defined yet, or instead you have reached the end of the list.

If you are writing an ordinary sequential Fortran program then lock-free/no-wait is not an issue.  If you are writing a multi-threaded / parallel program, then consistent access to the variables is an issue.

Here are some more examples: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Linked+list. 
Even better, linked lists in Fortran are clearly explained in the book "Fortran 90/95 Explained" by Metcalf and Reid.

Comment: I would like to know if lock-free data structures are possibl, do we have CAS like atmoic oporations in Fortan

Comment: Fortran itself doesn't provide atomic operations, that is beyond the language standard.  Fortran doesn't provide linked lists, it provides pointers and the ability for a pointer inside of a type to point to that type.  Typically you write your own linked list code; there are some user contributed codes at some of the links provided that can be used or adapted but no standard library.  If you have a multi-threaded program, you use the options of your threading library (OpenMP, MPI, ...) to guarantee consistent access to shared variables, including those that define a linked list.