# Fortran Pointer arithmetic

Tags: pointers, fortran

That's my first question post ever ... don't be cruel, please.

My problem is the following. I'd like to assign a fortran pointer as an expression. I think that's not possible by simple fortran techniques. But since new fortran versions seem to provide ways to handle things used in C and C++ (like c_ptr and c_f_pointer ... ), maybe someone knows a way to solve my problem. (I have not really in idea about C, but I read that pointer arithmetic is possible in C)
To make things more clear, here is the code which came to my mind immediately but isn't working:

```
program pointer

real(8),target :: a
real(8),pointer :: b

b=>a*2.0d0  ! b=>a is of course working

do i=1,10
   a=dble(i)*2.0d0
   write(*,*)b
end do

end program
```

I know that there are ways around this issue, but in the actual program, all of which came to my mind, would lead to much longer computation time and/or quite wiered code.

Thanks, a lot, in advance!

Best, Peter

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but in languages like c that allow pointer arithmetic the arithmetic is only addition/subraction. The "arithmetic" operates on memory address, so that `pointertoa + 1` yields a pointer to whatever is in the next memory loc after a.  I dont think this is possilbe in fortran, but in any case your multiplication makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for making the arithemtic clear. What I try to do is the following. I have a program depending on many input variables, and on of them is going o be changed inside of a do loop. But it depends on the input, which one is changed. However the loop construction is always the same and the parameters are stored in modules to be available in plenty of subroutines. Now I want to write some case construct after the parameter reading part to tell for the rest of the program which one is the parameter to be varied inside the loop, and in the loop I have a placeholder (here a).

Comment: Everything would work perfectly, if the placeholder would follow the same expression for each parameter. Unfortunately it doesn't. Of course I can write an if clause to each point, where it is used, but a single decision point at the beginning of the program looks nicer, is more controlled (in the sence of errors done by myself or people who have to use the code in the future) and it's faster by means of calculation time.
Sorry for the long answer, but you asked what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Incorporate your "what I am trying to do" description into the question itself.  That context is important for people trying to understand exactly what it is that you are asking - and what you are trying to do!

Comment: Sorry, I aimed to make it as briefly as possible.

Comment: Are you trying to make a lambda function?

Comment: Good question! So far, I didn't know about this concept to construct a function. But according to what I could read about it on Wikipedia, I'd say it's possible to write my problem as a series of lambda functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I'm getting closer to what I wanted to have (for those who are interested):

```
module test

real,target :: a
real, pointer :: c

abstract interface
   function func()
      real :: func
   end function func
end interface

procedure (func), pointer :: f => null ()

contains

function f1()
  real,target :: f1

  c=>a
  f1 = 2.0*c

  return
end function f1

end module

program test_func_ptrs

use test

implicit none

integer::i

f=>f1

do i=1,10
   a=real(i)*2.0
   write(*,*)f()
end do

end program test_func_ptrs
```

I would be completely satisfied if I could find a way to avoid the dummy arguments (at least in when I'm calling f).

Additional information: The point is that I want to define different functions f1 and deside before starting the loop, what f is going to be inside of the loop (depending on whatever input).

Answer (score 1):

From [Michael Metcalf](http://w3.pppl.gov/%7Ehammett/comp/f90tut/f90.tut6.html),

> Pointers are variables with the POINTER attribute; they are not a distinct data type (and so no 'pointer arithmetic' is possible).
>
> They are conceptually a descriptor listing the attributes of the objects (targets) that the pointer may point to, and the address, if any, of a target. They have no associated storage until it is allocated or otherwise associated (by pointer assignment, see below):

So your idea of `b=>a*2` doesn't work because `b` is being *assigned* to `a` and not given the *value* of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Expression, in general (there two and a half very significant exceptions), are not valid pointer targets.  Evaluation of an expression (in general) yields a value, not an object.

(The exceptions relate to the case where the overall expression results in a reference to a function with a data pointer result - in that case the expression can be used on the right hand side of a pointer assignment statement, or as the actual argument in a procedure reference that correspond to a pointer dummy argument or [perhaps - and F2008 only] in any context where a variable might be required, such as the left hand side of an ordinary assignment statement.  But your expressions do not result in such a function reference and I don't think the use cases are relevant to what you wnt to do. )

I think you want the value of b to change as the "underlying" value of a changes, as per the form of the initial expression.  Beyond the valid pointer target issue, this requires behaviour contrary to one of the basic principles of the language (most languages really) - evaluation of an expression uses the value of its primaries at the time the expression is evaluation - subsequent changes in those primaries do not result in a change in the historically evaluated value.

Instead, consider writing a function that calculates b based on a.

```
program pointer
  IMPLICIT NONE
  real(8) :: a
  do i=1,10
    a=dble(i)*2.0d0
    write(*,*) b(a)
  end do
contains
  function b(x)
    real(kind(a)), intent(in) :: x
    real(kind(a)) :: b
    b = 2.0d0 * x
  end function b
end program
```

Comment: Yes thanks, but this doesn't solve the issue. The problem is decribed in the comments above.

Comment: What you describe could be easily enough addressed using procedure pointers.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. But I guess it's somewhat close to what I posted below. Maybe you have a suggestion to improve what I have already. :-) I'm quite sure, that's possible. 
Anyhow thanks so far for your help. In case you answer me, please don't mind that I can answer only in some hours, since it's already 0:18 here. Best Peter

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic, in the sense of calculating address offsets from a pointer, is not allowed in Fortran.   Pointer arithmetic can easily cause memory errors and the authors of Fortran considered it unnecessary.   (One could do it via the back door of interoperability with C.)

Pointers in Fortran are useful for passing procedures as arguments, setting up data structures such as linked lists (e.g., [How can I implement a linked list in fortran 2003-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648779/how-can-i-implement-a-linked-list-in-fortran-2003-2008)), etc.